Algorithm for Retro-Azimuthal Projection
I am trying to solve the retro-azimuthal projection problem on an ellipsoid:
Given:

Point A = (lambda_A, phi_A)
d = Distance to Point B,
beta' = Direction FROM B (not from A!)

Searched: Point B = (lambda_B, phi_B)
I read this answer by @cffk Direct Geodesic with Point 2 Azimuth and it seems to be the solution and absolutely clear for all participants of the discussion. However, since I massively lack of the geodetic mathematics neither step 1 ("solve on a sphere") nor step 2 ("use Newton's method to converge") is clear to me. So, I am searching for a detailed help to understand what to do. I really want to understand what I need to do here, to enable me to solve similar problems on my own furtherly.
I could not find anything which really helped me specifically on this problem (either too general geometry or not very well explained...).
Step 1: What I tried for spherical solution

As I understand the blue values are given (being d the distance between A and B and N the north pole). If I am right, the green values can be calculated:

beta: I am not quite sure if the 360° rule applies on a sphere as well. But assuming this is right, beta is 360 - given beta'
b: is the distance between N and A, which can be calculated just by using phi_A and lambda_A
delta = phi_A - phi_B: With help of sinus rule and d, b, beta.

However, I don't know, how to get the coordinates of B. phi_B can be calculated throught delta and phi_A, right?
But how to get lambda_B?
Since I do not have alpha and a I cannot calculate the distance NB nor convert the problem into the direct geographic problem for which I would need alpha.
So, what am I missing here?
Step 2 (Newton's method):
I confess, I am completely lost here. Yes, I read about the method, I think I understood, what it should do in general (using an approx value, calculate a result, and use the result somehow to iterate the formula to get a better value, ...) but I am not able to use this for that (or even any) geodetic problem.
What is the approach here?
What do you do to create a formula to iterate which which value?

This is for me a completely foreign field.

Use spherical trigonometry to get a starting guess for the azimuth at the starting point.  This solution for your case is detailed in
this Wikipedia article.
Now solve the direct geodesic problem on the ellipsoid with this
starting azimuth and your given distance and try to follow the answer I
give to your linked question.

Thanks @cffk The link is extremely helpful, I was not aware of this site. I read your paper several times, but thanks for pointing out the right formula. However, since I don't fully understand the math behind it: How are m_12 and w_2 calculated. I see several formulas for m in the paper.

m_12 is an optional result given when computing geodesics via any of the implementations listed here.  w_2 is defined in Eq. (7) of Geodesics on an ellipsoid of revolution.

@cffk Thanks! In your paper, §10 you show the general equation for Newton's method for psi^(i + 1). There you are using the termin (theta^(i) - theta). I wonder what theta (without index) is. Is it the original guessed s_12, so is theta == theta^(0)?

@cffk Furthermore, (79) contains a. When I understood correctly, a is calculated by solving the direct problem using alpha^(i) and then a equals the distance from N to my B^(i), right?. So should a be thought of a ^(i), because it depends on the new alpha^(i) or is this a fixed value?

θ is one of the three known quantities for the triangle.  In the case of Problem 7, it is s_12.  The basic iteration for this case is: get a starting value for ψ, i.e., α_1, by solving the spherical problem; given φ_1 (which gives β_1), α_1, and α_2, the geodesic problem on the auxiliary sphere is completely specified and so σ_12, and hence s_12, can be found.  Since this won't in general be the given s_12, the equation above Eq. (77) can be used to obtain a refined estimate of α_1.  Repeat until convergence.  a in Eq. (79) is the equatorial radius.

@cffk And once more thanks for your incredible patience! I missed a as the radius, my bad. :D However, the θ is still not clear to me. I know it is s_12, but my point is, looking at the general Newton's formula you gave (the one without numeral reference above (77)) you mention (θ^(i) - θ). I guess θ^(i) is the value of s_12 in iteration step i. But a) s_12 is fixed, so why should there be an iterative value and b) what is the difference of θ^(i) and θ (without index). If they equal, the term would be 0. I'd appreciate if you could clarify this last puzzle piece :) Thanks so much!

To reiterate what I said in my previous reply: You're given φ_1, α_2, and s_12 and want to determine α_1.  Guess an initial value of α_1, α_1^(0).  Solve the problem given φ_1, α_1^(0), and α_2, to find s_12^(0).  Since in general s_12^(0) is not equal to s_12, apply Newton's method to find an updated value of α_1, α_1^(1).  Repeat this process until convergence.

Here's the solution more-or-less fleshed out.  This uses the Octave/MATLAB implementation of GeographicLib.  This is designed to illustrate Newton's method in action.  To make this a complete solution, you must generalize the spherical trigonometry.
Instructions:

save this file as retroazi.m
make sure geographiclib is in your Octave/MATLAB path
run the example shown

function [azi1, lat2, lon2] = retroazi(lat1, lon1, azi2, s12, ell)
% RETROAZI  Solve the retroazimuthal problem
% 
%   [azi1, lat2, lon2] = RETROAZI(lat1, lon1, azi2, s12, ell)
%
% Given lat1, lon1, azi2, s12, compute azi1, lat2, lon2.  ell specifies the
% ellipsoid via [a, e].
%
% CAUTION: This solves the triangle problems in a slipshod way assuming that
% the inverse trig functions return results in the correct quadrant.  This
% will therefore fail in some cases.  Nevertheless, it illustrates the basic
% Newton method (still to do: exit the loop when the method has converged).
% The following example works:
%  
% ell = [6.4e6, flat2ecc(1/50)];
% [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2] = deal(10, 0, 70, 80);
% % Solve the inverse problem for a geodesic
% [s12, azi1, azi2] = geoddistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, ell);
% % Solve the corresponding retroazimuthal problem
% [azi1x, lat2x, lon2x] = retroazi(lat1, lon1, azi2, s12, ell);
% % Check the results
% err = [azi1x, lat2x, lon2x] - [azi1, lat2, lon2]

  if nargin < 5, ell = defaultellipsoid; end
  a = ell(1);
  e2 = ell(2)^2;
  f = ecc2flat(ell(2));
  deg = pi/180;
  bet1 = atand((1-f) * tand(lat1));
  sig12 = (s12 / a) / deg;
  % Solve the SSA probelm following Wikipedia
  omg12 = asind(sind(sig12) * sind(azi2) / cosd(bet1));
  azi1 = 2 * acotd( cotd((omg12+azi2)/2) * ...
                    sind((90-bet1+sig12)/2) / sind((90-bet1-sig12)/2) );
  for i = 1:10
    % Solve the trig problem on the auxiliary sphere to give sig12
    azi0 = asind(sind(azi1) * cosd(bet1));
    bet2 = acosd(sind(azi0) / sind(azi2));
    sig1 = atan2d(sind(bet1), cosd(azi1) * cosd(bet1));
    sig2 = atan2d(sind(bet2), cosd(azi2) * cosd(bet2));
    sig12 = sig2 - sig1;
    % Solve the direct problem to give s12x
    [lat2,lon2,~, ~,m12,~,~, s12x] = ...
        geodreckon(lat1, lon1, sig12, azi1, ell, 1);
    bet2 = atand((1-f) * tand(lat2));
    w2 = sqrt(1 - e2 * cosd(bet2).^2);
    % The correction to azi1, see Eq (79) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1215
    dazi1 = -(s12x - s12) / ...
            (m12 * tand(azi2) - ...
             a * w2 / (tand(azi1) * tand(bet2) * cosd(azi2)))
    azi1 = azi1 + dazi1 / deg;
  end
end

ADDENDUM
By the way, you should always explore the nature of your problem.   Given lat1, lon1, azi2, s12, solve the direct problem with lat1, lon1, azi1x, s12 to give azi2x and plot az12x-azi2 against azi1x.  Thus:
azi1x = [-180:0.25:180];
[~,~,azi2x] = geodreckon(lat1, lon1, s12, azi1x, ell);
dazi2 = mod(azi2x - azi2, 360);
dazi2(dazi2 > 180) = dazi2(dazi2 > 180) - 360;
plot(azi1x, dazi2, 'x');

This will tell you if a unique solution exists.

Thanks for your work. I could test this now. Running exactly this code in Matlab with [azi1, lat2, lon2] = retroazi(52.0, 13.0, 123.0, 100000.0, [6378137.0, 0.081819190842622]) the function returns 51.5, 14.2, 122.05°. As you can see, the returned azi1 is similar to azi2, instead of the opposite one. That yields coordinates which are on the wrong side as the expected ones. I expect something like 52.5, 11.8, 304°. Since I did not change anything, I'd kindly ask, if there's a mistake somewhere?

My convention is that azi1 and azi2 are "forward" azimuths pointing in the direction of travel from point 1 to point 2 (and beyond).  Adjust as necessary if your convention is different.

I am not quite sure what you mean with "adjust". I just ran your code. As input I gave all the data, I currently have. I search for the azimuth from A (the input parameters lat1/lon1) to B (output lat2/lon2), which is azi1, right? What I have is the azi2 from the unknown B to A. So I entered A (52.0/13.0), azi2 from B to A (123°) and got azi1 (supposed to be A to B) == 122° (which is only 1° difference to entered azi2, which seems to be wrong at all, since I expect something around 304°). Debugging shows that azi1 is ~122 already at the spherical initialisation, though. Can't you reproduce?

I define azi2 as the azimuth of the geodesic from A to B at B.  You define it as the azimuth of the geodesic from B to A at B.  Add 180d to your azi2 to get my azi2.

Sometimes it's that easy! Now I understand the way. I hope I can find the edge cases in which there's no solution or something :) Thanks for your awesome patience! Happy holidays!
